# addClass() not adding class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a class to a element but it doesn't seem to be adding the class.

This is what my code looks like:

```
var wrapper='<div class="float-notification"></div>';
var message="<span>" + message + "</span>";
      if(error==true){
        var close_button = '<span class="float-notification-close" style="float:right;cursor:pointer;">X</span>';
        var content = $(wrapper).append(message + close_button);
        $(this).append(content);
        //give wrapper a error class 
        $(wrapper).addClass('error');         
      }else{.....
```

I've also tried this with `$(wrapper).append("Foo Bar")` and it works as expected, So why won't `addClass()` work?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/407pxatv/

Comment: you are assigning value to variable but where is the code to print that in document

Comment: what are you trying to achieve

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U need to append it to body

```
var wrapper='<div class="float-notification"></div>';
$(wrapper).addClass('error').appendTo('body');
```

It works!

Comment: You need to add class first and then append it to body because the div in assigned to a variable and you are adding the div first without class and then adding class in variable which makes no sense. For that you have to update the div from variable so its better to add class first and then append it to body with added class..

Answer (score 3):

`$(wrapper)` converts the string of HTML into a DOM node and wraps it in a jQuery object.

`.addClass('error')` then adds a class to that DOM node.

You then don't do anything with the return value and you don't use a method such as `appendTo` to put in to the document. So the jQuery object (and the DOM node inside it) is discarded.

(The original string of HTML is never modified).

Comment: But then why does `$('#something').html('...')` write down to the document directly? Should it not insert into the DOM node and wait for the node to be truly appended?